# kendoDatePicker is not a function error to logged out users

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, sitefinity

I'm using kendo UI Datepicker and the problem is that the style is not applyed when the user is logged out. I'm receiving "KendoDatepicker is not a function" error in the browser console.

I find out that we should load the jquery scripts before kendo's, and a likely source of the problem could be the load of Jquery twice. source

I searched through out the project and i'm not finding any duplicate.

however when I investigated the Sources in the browser I found out that not all the ScriptResources.axd are loaded when the user is logged out.

When the user is Logged out it receives only:

- jQuery Migrate v1.2.1
- MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.debug.js version: 4.0.0.0
- jQuery v1.11.2
- MicrosoftAjax.debug.js version: 4.0.0.0
- Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd
- WebResource.axd (2 files)

  ---

This are the scripts loaded when the user is logged in:

- jQuery Migrate v1.2.1
- MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.debug.js version:  4.0.0.0
- jQuery v1.11.2
- MicrosoftAjax.debug.js V 4.0.0.0
- Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd
- WebResource.axd (2 files)
- RequireJS 2.1.6
- Telerik.Sitefinity Version:     8.1.5800.0
- Kendo UI v2015.2.624
- http://www.JSON.org/json2.js
- jQuery outside events - v1.1
  I don't know if this is the problem but i'm not seeing any other difference between a logged in and logged out user.

This are my imports in the master page:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <script src="../../../../../Scripts/kendo/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../../../../Scripts/kendo/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../../../../Scripts/kendo/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>
    <link href="../../../../../Content/kendo/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../../../../../Content/kendo/kendo.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link href="../../../../../Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../../../../../Content/header.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../../../../../Content/content.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../../../../../Content/footer.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are missin the kendo kendo.all.ui.js or your custom rolled from kendo with date picker. When users are logged in sitefinity loads kendo for inline editing.

Comment: Hi Jon R. If that's true kendo.all.ui.js should appear when the user is logged in right? Addicionally, i'm not finding any information about a kendo.all.ui.js where can i find it?

Comment: If you look at this demo only two scripts reference jQuery and kendo.all.js sorry the "ui" part was a mistype.